# Two monitors with Mac Mini - one displays black despite receiving a signal

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, mac-mini

My Mac Mini outputs to my two new monitors - [Dell U2311Hs](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/products/Displays/productdetail.aspx?c=usl=en&cs=19&sku=320-9270).

The LED on the bezel displays blue when receiving a signal, or yellow otherwise. Both screens are displaying blue.

It also seems my Mini can *see* both of them...

[image: Displays]

However, one of them is black. It just displays black, but appears to be receiving a signal (when I turn the Mac off, it *then* displays *No Signal*).

To make things weirder, on startup, the boot up (white with Apple logo) appears on the right monitor (the one that now displays black).

Occasionally, it flickers up on the black screen for 1 second.

I have tried *Detect Displays*. It appears to do nothing.

I'm also running a dual monitor KVM. Video connections are DVI-D.

How can I fix this situation?

Thanks.

### Update

This is the weirdest thing - I used the DVI-D cable that came with the KVM and it *seems* to have fixed it - I didn't both because it looks identical to any other DVI cable (in form an pin out).

So, I will accept an answer if someone can tell me what may be the difference in these cables?

Comment: Have you switched output signals (i.e. cables)? What about exclusively connecting the nonfunctioning screen? Aside from the flickering, it sounds like you just have a black wallpaper, you're sure that's not the case?

Comment: @Daniel Beck Definitely not a black wallpaper - no mouse pointer or background (when it flickers up, you can see the background). Also, it seems way too black to be black background (doesn't seem to be *any* light on the screen). Similar problem when avoiding the KVM - but I will test again now anyway. Thanks for the comment.